# Im writing a recursive function that has to wait for the function to finish,using async/await, how can I do this the right way?

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks, async-await, promise

I want to make a recursive function that waits till the value distance is renewed.

```
`  const calculateDistance = async() => {
    const loc = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy: true})
    const distanceCalc = await getPreciseDistance(
      {latitude: 51.493280, longitude: 4.294605 },
      {latitude: loc.coords.latitude, longitude: loc.coords.longitude})
      await SetDistance(distanceCalc)
      calculateDistance();
      return true
    }`
```

I tried to make a second function to wait for the function to finish lik this:

```
  const calculateDistance = (loc) => {
const distanceCalc =  getPreciseDistance(
  {latitude: 51.493280, longitude: 4.294605 },
  {latitude: loc.coords.latitude, longitude: loc.coords.longitude})
  SetDistance(distanceCalc)
  return true
}
const calculateDistance1 = async() => {
  const loc = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy: true})
  const truet = await calculateDistance(loc);
  calculateDistance1();
}
```

and then repeat the function but that did not work. I also tried to solve it with if statements that get changed when the function finished.The errors I get are "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:2)" and also flushedQueu.

Comment: What is the purpose of this recursive call?  Is there no condition to stop the recursion?

Comment: In your second function, you're not `await`ing `getPreciseDistance`. Why?

Comment: @ Trincot I want to get an updated location, allways, I dont need to stop the recursion yet, ofcourse I will stop it, but i haven't programmed the function to stop it yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. return the promise object to the calling instance
2. you need some loop breaking clause

Example code demonstrating what you might need to achieve:

```js
let idx = 0;

const calculateDistance = async () => {
  console.debug(`calculateDistance iteration ${idx}`);

  // ... your code

  idx++;
  if (idx < 5) {
    return calculateDistance();
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
};

console.debug("starting");
calculateDistance().then(() => {
  console.debug("done");
});
```